# Autofill every n rows

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

How can I autofill the entirety of column B based on column A but with n empty rows in between each letter?

```
Column A:

a
b
c
```

```
Column B:

a
...
...
b
...
...
c
```

I have tried the VBA code below:

```
Range("A1:A3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The code works with numbers but not when the cell references a formula (in this case, `=A1`, ...) as the code seems to reference the row the formula is, instead of the list in column A.

For example, the code inserts the formula a row after `c` in `B7`, however would insert `=A7` instead of `=A4` which would be the letter `d`.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert `n row` for each value in Column A, I will use `offset` to solve it, here is the solution and hope you find it useful:

```
Sub ty()

Dim count As Long, i As Long, nextrow As Long

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
nextrow = 1

For i = 1 To count
    Sheet1.Cells(nextrow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    nextrow = Cells(nextrow, 2).Offset(3, 1).Row
Next

End Sub
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

In order to preserve the formula into new cells, then you may need `copy` method` by change this part:

```
For i = 1 To count
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy Sheet1.Cells(nextrow, 2)
    nextrow = nextrow + 3
Next
```

Comment: Why such a complicated `offset` if you can just calculate `nextrow = nextrow + 3`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, ya, i did not think about that. it is more straightforward :)

Comment: Accept my answer if helping you :)

Comment: @KinSiang Just one more thing, I have a set of IF statements in the A column that only activate when in the B column as the formula are spills. Your code correctly inserts them in the B column, however, the IF statement is set to the deactivated state (or the state the IF statement was originally in the A column). Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Ya, it can be achieved by using `copy` method, please find the edited answer and test if it work as per your expectation :)

Comment: @KinSiang Your edit did insert the formula into the cell, however, now it goes back to the initial problem. The formula in column B references the row it is in rather than the elements in column A. For example, the letter B is referencing `=A4` rather than `=A2`. What do you think?

Comment: Try this line `Sheet1.Cells(nextrow, 2).Formula = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Formula`, should be work as per your expectation.

Comment: @KinSiang Yes the line does insert the formula with the correct cell reference, but it there is yet another problem, the `@` symbol in the inserted formula stops the formula from presenting the expected output (stops the formula from spilling). Upon the removal of the `@`, the formula works correctly. Do you know of this?

Comment: ok... I suggest you open new thread again, i think @ symbol problem other expert know better than me.

Comment: @KinSiang Thank you for your help. Turns out `Formula2` works as this removes the implicit intersection operator `@` but maintains the cell increments in column A.

Comment: Ya, if you perform macro recorder, it will auto-populate `Formula2` for all case, quite a good function and glad you find it out.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoFill Every n Rows

- You run `GetGappedColumnTEST`. `GetGappedColumn` is being called by the `GetGappedColumnTEST`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section and the workbook, and rename the `Sub` appropriately.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetGappedColumnTEST()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "B1"
    Const dGap As Long = 2

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = GetGappedColumn(wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst), dGap)
    
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = Data
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1) _
            .Offset(drCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
End Sub

Function GetGappedColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Gap As Long = 0) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetGappedColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError

    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If Gap < 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set srg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
       
    Dim sData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount + rCount * Gap - Gap, 1 To 1)
    Dim d As Long: d = 1
    Dim s As Long
    For s = 1 To rCount - 1
        dData(d, 1) = sData(s, 1)
        d = d + 1 + Gap
    Next s
    dData(d, 1) = sData(s, 1)

    GetGappedColumn = dData
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Does your code provide any advantage over the simpler alternative above?